# Using PRAW to call Reddit API. Need help interpreting the created datetime returned

Tags: reddit, praw

After hovering on the "submitted 2 months ago" I can get the created date of the post on reddit UI.

In my case, the post I'm looking at has this datetime: 
Fri Dec 18 02:06:06 2015 UTC

But when I call the reddit API using praw I'm getting this in the created_utc field: 
1450404366.0

I'm not able to translate "Fri Dec 18 02:06:06 2015 UTC" to "1450404366.0"

Please help!

Comment: That's a `unix timestamp` that needs converted into a readable date.

Comment: are you using python?

Comment: yes! i am using python

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what reddit is giving you is a [`UNIX TIMESTAMP`](http://www.epochconverter.com/) which is basically the seconds since Jan 01 1970. (UTC) that needs to be converted into a human-readable date time setup.

I would suggest using the [`datatime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) module in **python**:

example usage:

```
import datetime
print(
    datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int("1284101485")
    ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.